# How to trigger a rule when clicking on a link?

Tags: 7, views, rules

I am looking for a way to trigger a rule when clicking on a link. What I am actually trying to do, is fireing a VBO with a Button, instead of the Dropdown solution. For this, I created a Rules-Component that does the job, but I don't know how to fire that rule, as it should start from within a view.

Answer (score 3):

take a look at [Rules Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link):

> This module lets you create links which trigger arbitrary
>   functionality with the help of Rules.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, rules components cannot be triggered on their own. You will need to create a rule for that that will be triggered when one event occurs. Then you should write some code. I would do it like this:

- have a custom page in your module (Eg: "actions/my-custom-rule")
- trigger the rule using `rules_invoke_event('the_event', $params);`
- redirect the user back to the previous page using `drupal_goto(drupal_get_destination());`

If the event is something custom, you need to define the event in your module. Find out more about integrating rules in your module from [here](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-custom-rules-how-write-your-own-events-conditions-actions-and-custom-object-custom-token).

Comment: Thanks for that info. Then I missunderstood rules. When I do have my own implementation in a custom module I can do the action there without rules anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a way to trigger a rule when clicking on a link.

This is answered correctly by @geoff

> What I am actually trying to do, is fireing a VBO with a Button, instead of the Dropdown solution. For this, I created a Rules-Component that does the job, but I don't know how to fire that rule, as it should start from within a view.

This is a setting in the views panel. Click the field "Views bulk operations" and select to expose each component as a separate button instead of a droplist under "Bulk operations settings".